# Minimize the ratio involving the ellipse

Tags: calculus, inequality, analytic-geometry, maxima-minima

> Let $P$ be any point on the curve $\dfrac{x^2}{4}+\dfrac{y^2}{3}=1$,
> and $A,B$ be two fixed points $\left(\dfrac{1}{2},0\right)$ and
> $(1,1)$ respectively. Find the minimum value of
> $\dfrac{|PA|^2}{|PB|}$.

Assume $x=2\cos\theta,y=\sqrt{3}\sin\theta$, then
$$\dfrac{|PA|^2}{|PB|}=\frac{\left(2\cos\theta-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+(\sqrt{3}\sin\theta-0)^2}{\sqrt{\left(2\cos\theta-1\right)^2+(\sqrt{3}\sin\theta-1)^2}},$$
but which is not so easy to tackle.

[WolframeAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Minimize%20%20%28%282cosx-1%2F2%29%5E2%2B%28sqrt%283%29sinx-0%29%5E2%29%2F%28sqrt%28%282cosx-1%29%5E2%2B%28sqrt%283%29sinx-1%29%5E2%29%29) gives the result $1$.

Comment: Since $\frac{|PA|^2}{|PB|}$ is always positive, it will takes its minimum at the same place where $\dfrac{|PA|^4}{|PB|^2}$ is minimized. This may seem harder, but it doesn't involve a square root. And once you take the derivative, it doesn't matter what the denominator is, the entire fraction is $0$ when the numerator is $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Denote $c = \cos \theta$ and $s = \sin\theta$.

We have
$$|\mathrm{PA}|^2 = (2c - 1/2)^2 + (s\sqrt 3 - 0)^2= c^2 - 2c + \frac{13}{4}$$
and
$$|\mathrm{PB}|^2 = (2c - 1)^2 + (s\sqrt 3 - 1)^2 
= c^2 - 4c + 5 - 2\sqrt 3\, s.$$

We have
\begin{align*}
 |\mathrm{PA}|^4 - |\mathrm{PB}|^2
 &= (c^2 - 2c + 13/4)^2 - (c^2 - 4c + 5 - 2\sqrt 3\, s)\\
 &= (c^2 - 2c + 13/4)^2 - c^2 + 4c - 5 + 2\sqrt 3\, s\\
 &\ge 0
\end{align*}
where we have used
$(c^2 - 2c + 13/4)^2 - c^2 + 4c - 5 > 0$ and
\begin{align*}
 &[(c^2 - 2c + 13/4)^2 - c^2 + 4c - 5]^2 - (2\sqrt 3\, s)^2\\
 =\,& [(c^2 - 2c + 13/4)^2 - c^2 + 4c - 5]^2 - 12(1-c^2)\\
 =\,&\frac{1}{256}(64c^6 - 448c^5 + 1776c^4 - 4128c^3 + 6524c^2 - 6236c + 4849)(2c-1)^2\\ 
 \ge\,& 0.
\end{align*}

On the other hand, when $\theta = \frac{5\pi}{3}$,
we have $|\mathrm{PA}|^4 - |\mathrm{PB}|^2 = 0$ and $\frac{|\mathrm{PA}|^2}{|\mathrm{PB}|} = 1$.

Thus, the minimum of $\frac{|\mathrm{PA}|^2}{|\mathrm{PB}|}$ is $1$.

Answer (score 0):

Doing what @Paul Sinclair already commented and using multiple angle formulae
$$\dfrac{|PA|^4}{|PB|^2}=\frac{-256 \cos (\theta )+92 \cos (2 \theta )-16 \cos (3 \theta )+2 \cos
   (4 \theta )+259}{8 \left(-4 \sqrt{3} \sin (\theta )-8 \cos (\theta
   )+\cos (2 \theta )+11\right)}$$ Computing the derivative, its numerator is "just"
$$(15-8 \cos (\theta )+2 \cos (2 \theta )) \times$$
$$\left(24 \sqrt{3}-40 \sin (\theta )+45 \sin (2 \theta )-12 \sin (3 \theta )+\sin
   (4 \theta )-40 \sqrt{3} \cos (\theta )-8 \sqrt{3} \cos (2 \theta )+6
   \sqrt{3} \cos (3 \theta )\right)$$ The first factor does not cancel and with all these $\sqrt{3} $ in the remaining term, if the solution is simple, it is a multiple of $\frac \pi 3$ and, just trying, one zero of the derivative is $\theta=\frac {5\pi} 3$ and then the result.